# MVC4 WebAPI reject invalid enum values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

How can I make JSON.NET / MVC 4 WebAPI reject integer values for which the enum has no member? Eg:

If I have this model:

```
public enum Colour { Red = 1 };

public class Model
{
  public Colour Colour { get; set; }
}

Model Post(Model model)
{
   // model.Colour could be 99, 34234234, 0 etc, etc
}
```

If I post `{ Color: 9999 }`, I end up with a model where model.Color = 999 and I want to return a Bad Request status code instead.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One option is to write a validator:

```
public class ValidEnumValueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        Type enumType = value.GetType();
        bool valid = Enum.IsDefined(enumType, value);
        if (!valid)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(String.Format("{0} is not a valid value for type {1}", value, enumType.Name));
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Use as:

```
public enum Color {Red = 1, Blue = 2}

public class Car
{
    [ValidEnumValue]
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller, `ModelState.IsValid` would be `false`.
You can also throw a `ValidationException`, if you really want to fail the request, but I'm not *quite* sure that is how they should be used.

Comment: Note: I used MVC 4 to test it, not Web API, but I think it should be the same.

Comment: This is still a great answer in 2017 with ASP.NET Core that, yes, is completely valid with Web API.

Comment: I'm struggling with how this could work since you are relying on the data type of "value" to already be the Enum type so how would this test ever fail?  When I tried this code in WebAPI2, "value" was populated with the default value when garbage was passed in so it of course passes the test.  With that said, it seem like WebAPI2 works out of the box when you leverage a check to ModelState.IsValid.

Comment: What I'm struggling with now, though, is (A) I have no control over the message for that failure and (B) that use does not work when the enum value is not provided at and the [Required] attribute does not seem to solve (because of the same problem with the default value being used)

Comment: @retsvek - These are excellent questions. I suggest you'll post a new question (or two), you'll get a better answer that way. (this answer is almost 4 years old!)

Comment: Can this be applied at the application level? Rather than having to tag all properties that are of enum types.  It seems really easy to miss a spot.

Answer (score 40):

It turns out the [EnumDataTypeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.enumdatatypeattribute), which comes with the out-of-the-box ValidationAttributes in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace, does an [Enum.Defined check](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/f64e71f762daf233523e6ac112bc8cb5c318e7af/src/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/src/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/EnumDataTypeAttribute.cs#L106).

Once I applied this attribute to my view model, out-of-range integer values failed validation:

```
public enum Color {Red = 1, Blue = 2}

public class Car
{
    [EnumDataType(typeof(Color))]
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

Note: values that can be parsed into integers that are defined on the enum will still pass validation due to the default behavior of enum model binding. This means, for example, `true` will be parsed as `1`, which would be valid for this enum. I assume characters that can be mapped to integers will also work.

If you only want one flavor of enum parsing to work, be it string or integer, consider using that specific type on your view model, and then write a custom `ValidationAttribute` that takes in the enum type, validating that the string or integer on your view model matches a value in the enum.

Comment: Though the above answer is accepted as the solution, this answer works like a charm for me.

Comment: Not working for me in WebApi - is this perhaps only for MVC controllers?

Comment: @mcintyre321 It _should_ work as long as other validation attributes are being ran. There is nothing special about this attribute as far as MVC vs. WebAPI is concerned.

Comment: I'm glad I scrolled down to find this answer. I almost wrote (well, copied and pasted...) custom code when none was needed!

Comment: I really frustrated I should do that instead of out-of-the-box under-the-hood validation as I expect. WTF