# Pass Enum Parameter to WebApi method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Trying to pass enum type value to WebApi but it is accepting any value other than enum integers.

can we restrict to accept only enum values?

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/getName/{Gender}")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get(Gender gender)
    {
        Gender g = gender;

        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Enum Value

```
public enum Gender
{
    Male,
    FeMale
}
```

Ex:

1. http://localhost:58984/api/getName/1 - Resolving it to FeMale
2. http://localhost:58984/api/getName/6 - it is accepting 6 but I would like to throw an exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC4 WebAPI reject invalid enum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082062/mvc4-webapi-reject-invalid-enum-values)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/39789818/5236014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check this manually, ASP.NET MVC does not to that for you:

```
Type enumType = gender.GetType();
bool isEnumValid = Enum.IsDefined(enumType, gender);
if (!isEnumValid) {
  throw new Exception("...");
}
```

Instead of throwing an exception, you could also use a validator on the model that checks if the enum is correct.

The reason why the invalid enum is passed in through the parameter is, because enums are integers, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35117265/c-sharp-enum-tryparse-parses-invalid-number-strings/35117297#35117297).

Comment: It is already an enum, not a string. In order to use TryParse() we had to make a gender.ToString() and parse again. Why is TryParse the better option then? And wouldn't that be Enum.TryParse<Gender>()?

Comment: I take it back, I didn't realise web api would turn the enum into a integer if it was invalid.

Comment: By the way: It tried the Enum.TryParse() and that does actually not work, see [demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gcrZ1z). Invalid numbers can still be parsed. And this seems to be the normal behavior as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35117297/4636870) states.